# How to get user's input text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to design a square-root calculator using javascript. I want the user to write the number to be 'square-rooted' into an input area. After that I want to get what user types in that input area with javascript. Here's my HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" id = 'sqrt'>
</form>
```

When user types a number inside input area, my plan is to get this number with a DOM method inside my javascript file. But I couldn't figure how? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getElementById` DOM API function, and the get the value using the property with the same name:

```
document.getElementById('sqrt').value
```

This yields the number from the field.

You should call this code snippet in the onclick handler of the button, as on page load it is empty! So:

```
function nihai() {
    var x = document.getElementById('sqrt').value;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why but it doesn't work. Here's it http://jsbin.com/segefekoti/2/. Thanks.

Comment: Added an extra line, it tells your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can get the square root by using

```
var num =  Math.sqrt(document.getElementById('sqrt').value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. But I'm trying to write a function that does what Math.sqrt method does just for practice.

Comment: @BarristanSelmy: implementing the `Math.sqrt` method in all its glory is in fact rather difficult. Do you need to do all of it, or just do something more basic like finding a rounded down square root for integers?

Comment: Yes i know it. I am just trying to do son exercise on what I've learnt so far. Nothing serious:) It can work with integers for now. But I'm trying to improve it in a way it will calculate numbers like 44,12. But I'm stuck to be clear.